# Interpolate where OnTriggerExit is called

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my code, I use OnTriggerExit to detect when an object leaves a previous cube's space, and then create another cube. However, because of delta time, the cube gets placed slightly late creating these varied size gaps:

[image: Cubes with gaps]

How do I get rid of them, and position the cube properly?
I am pretty sure I need to interpolate, but I am not sure exactly what/how to do it. If needed, I have the last cube, last frame and current transforms, as well as current speed (in Vector3 form). Thanks!

Comment: Maybe this api could you.https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.ClosestPoint.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you leave, set `this` cube's position to `lastCube.position + size_offset`, where `size_offset` is however big your cubes are in the direction that they're moving.

You already have a reference to the previous cube (due to the `OnTriggerExit` [supplying you with a reference to the other collider](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerExit.html), from which you can get the needed `Transform`).

Comment: And how can I get the size_offset?

Comment: It's the size of your cube. I don't know how big your cube is or which direction its moving in.

Comment: yes, but is there a way to measure the size of something in a certain direction? The cube may be substituted for other objects

Comment: Option 1: the object's scale. Option 2: the object's collider's size. Option 3: use a raycast.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is strictly deltatime,s fault. Physisc engine has its on timestep, and if the velocity is x, the object will travel x*dt per physics step. So, by the time the next round of triggers is fired, the object is already penetrating. You could either use a rigidbody (easier but may not give expected results), or check penetration depth with that collider and offset that

Comment: Could you explain the two options in more detail? I dont understand them, but they sound helpfull.

Comment: when you use a rigidbody, the physics engine will not allow the two obejcts to intersect, they will bounce instead. Without a rigidbody, you get collision / trigger callbacks, but the objects are allowed to intersect

Comment: The rigidbody was necessary for triggers to work and can be turned nonkinematic, disabling physics

Comment: You may be right, there's many ways. For me a very enlightening moment came when I read about how they wrote their WheelColliders. Apparently down to earth physics simulation is not always the best way, and apparently after a lot of research they faked the physics using raycasts and adding forces based on that, so theres no ACTUAL need for there to be any rigidboidies, at least as long as you don't need stuff behaving as it have mass